# Syncing iTunes between 2 accounts on the same computer

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, sharing, accounts

I have 2 accounts (*home* and *work*) on my MacBook, and would like have both accounts accessing the same iTunes library.

I have some success by putting the iTunes Library in the public folder of my *home* account, so my *work* account can access the same files too. However, what I would like is to have my Podcasts sync as well.  So that when I plug in my iPhone, I can sync my Podcast regardless which account I am on.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: This is covered at:

 - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/how-to-share-an-itunes-library-with-other-user-accounts-on-the-same-machine
 - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17675/can-i-have-two-mac-users-share-one-itunes-library-on-the-same-mac

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, I can share music, but I want my podcast to be synced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not entirely possible as per this Apple discussions thread:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1521856?start=0&tstart=0